# Ubuntu 13.10 font problem on 30" Dell U3014 at 2560x1600

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, resolution, fonts

I have 13.10, with a Nvidea 8600GTS, driver 304.88, xserver 1.14.3, working fine with 2x 24" 1920x1200 screens in twinview.  I have swapped one out for a Dell U3014 but whilst getting the reported 2560x1600 resolution, I find the font is crumpled, blurry and unreadbale, switching res to 1920x1200 (which worked on the 24") results in the same.

What can I do to make the fonts readable?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as ever, I managed to figure out the problem, which was (a) that whilst nvidia-settings declared the screen at 2560x1600 it wasn't, it was running at 1280x1600 (the OSD provides this), hence the squashed font effect.

The solution is simple, use the thicker DVI cable supplied in the box, apparently it makes all the difference, res now reports correctly on OSD.

Comment: For anyone who finds this through google, like I did: The dell 30* series - at least the 3014 this person had, and the 3008WFP I've got - require a Dual-Link DVI cable to run at the full 2560x1600 resolution over DVI. I assume that's what "the thicker DVI cable supplied in the box" is.

The alternative is to use the DisplayPort connector.